# ES6 Recursive method using requestanimationframe

Tags: javascript, three.js, es6-class

I have been trying to make a simple scenemanager class that can also handle rendering.

```
class SceneManager {
    constructor() {

        this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
        this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 10000 );

        this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        this.renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    }
    CreateScene(){
        document.body.appendChild( this.renderer.domElement );
        this.scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0x777777));
    }
    RenderCycle(){
        requestAnimationFrame(this.RenderCycle());
        this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    }  
}
```

and calling the methods like so

```
var sceneManager = new SceneManager();
sceneManager.CreateScene();
sceneManager.RenderCycle();
```

However I am receiving this error:

```
scenemanager.class.js:18 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at SceneManager.RenderCycle (scenemanager.class.js:18)
at SceneManager.RenderCycle (scenemanager.class.js:19)
at SceneManager.RenderCycle (scenemanager.class.js:19)
at SceneManager.RenderCycle (scenemanager.class.js:19)
at SceneManager.RenderCycle (scenemanager.class.js:19)
```

I understand this is because it is immediately invoking RenderCycle() but Im not sure how else do go about it.

Any help and guidance would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: I believe you need to take the parenthesis off the this.RenderCycle(). Because it executes it rather than sending in a handle to the function.
requestAnimationFrame(this.RenderCycle());

Comment: Cannot read property 'RenderCycle' of null .  perhaps because the scope of this has changed? @GordonKushner

Comment: Sorry. I'm lost after that point. Does it come back as null at the first call or after recursion?

Comment: After the first call

Comment: You need to either bind `RenderCycle` or use `class-transform-properties` or something like that to be able to do: `RenderCycle = ()=>{...}`.

Comment: Also rename `RenderCycle` to `renderCycle`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bind `renderCycle` to `this` class in your constructor, and use camelCase (the standard in js):

```
class SceneManager {

  constructor() {

    this.renderCycle = this.renderCycle.bind(this);

    // ... 
  }

  renderCycle() {

    requestAnimationFrame(this.renderCycle);
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
  }  
}
```